# Angular getting the parent class reference of component

Tags: angular

In Angular (v5.2), I have a resolver implementation for the router.

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyCustomRouteResolver implements Resolve<Observable<String>> {
    resolve(router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, routerState: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<String> {
     let componentName:string = (<Type<any>>router.component).name; //gives the class name of the component

      //some logic
    }
    }
```

My AngularComponent extends from a class called `BaseComponent` which has a `getId()` function.

Now when I try below code

```
if(router.component instanceof BaseComponent){
//some logic
}
```

, the above condition doesn't satisfy. How can I get the reference to `BaseComponent` so that I can invoke the `getId()` function? Something like the below

```
let baseComp:BaseComponent = (<BaseComponent>)router.component;
console.log(baseComp.getId());
```

Comment: you want to call a method inside Base Component from resolver?

Comment: yes, i want to call it from resolver.